# Syncdb - access denied but mysql -u root -p - access granted

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to access my database through `Django` (`Bitnami djangostack).
Here are my databases settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangostack',
        'HOST': '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock', #or 127.0.0.1
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'bitnami'
    }
}
```

When I execute `python manage.py syncdb` I get:

```
1045, Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But I can login MySQL with this username and password.

`djangostack` DB exists.

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you tried without HOST and PORT number ?

Comment: Yes i did. Not working

Answer (score 0):

you can easily find out possible bug in your code by doing some testing :)

1)create new user in mysql and use that in settings.py and test:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON djangostack.* To 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

giving all permissions to user on djangostack database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON djangostack.* To 'user'@'hostname'
```

2) remove PORT argument test
*Default port will be 8000.So your admin is accessible at localhost:8000/admin

3) change HOST to 127.0.0.1 test